# Channel Entries - Author Id Parse order

Tags: channel-entries, parse-order, author

I have this code here

```
{exp:channel:entries
        author_id="1|CURRENT_USER"
        channel="foo"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
        dynamic="no"
        orderby="entry_id"
        sort="asc"
        parse="inward"
}
    ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This code is supposed to return all the `foo` entries which as authored by

- the admin (author_id=1)
- the current logged in user (author_id=45)

The problem that I am having is that it doesn't get the correct entries.

I tried 2 variations as listed below but they didn't work.

```
author_id="1|{member_id}"
author_id="1|{logged_in_member_id}"
```

However, when hardcoding the values

```
author_id="1|45"
```

It returned the correct entries.

How do I solve this problem since I can't use hardcoded values in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be work , but it doesn't I think it is a bug.

anyway u can work around this problem with exp:member:custom_profile_data

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}   
{exp:channel:entries
        author_id="1|{member_id}"
        channel="foo"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
        dynamic="no"
        orderby="entry_id"
        sort="asc"
        parse="inward"
}     

.....

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Currently CURRENT_USER can use as alone value in channel loop but if u want to use CURRENT_USER in the channel loop instead off custom_profile_data , u can hack the EE code.

go to system/expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php Line 1845

```
$sql .= ee()->functions->sql_andor_string($author_id, 'm.member_id');
```

To

```
$author_id = str_replace('CURRENT_USER',ee()->session->userdata('member_id'),$author_id);
$sql .= ee()->functions->sql_andor_string($author_id, 'm.member_id');
```

**Note: And you can aloes use embed templates to solve problem like this.**

Regard's.

Comment: I think the code above using {exp:member:custom_profile_data} only applies for ExpressioneEngine 1.x

Comment: this code is work fine and I check it on EE2.8.0

Comment: Ok it seems to work when I used `{member_id}` instead of `{logged_in_member_id}`